# Dropdownlist Databind automatically setting selected value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I filled a dropdownlist with active directory users, not a big deal and works great.  The problem is it's setting `<option selected="selected" value="user">User</option>`
 on the first one and won't let me change it in the code behind. Is there a way to keep it from automatically setting that `selected="selected"`?

Comment: Welcome to `SO` are you binding you dropdown on page load event?

Comment: Quick replies wow and Thank you.  Soner yes sir and its wrapped up in a if(!Page.IsPostback)..  Maybe I should say that I don't want ANY value selected until the user selects it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dlst" runat="server" Width="200px" 
          AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="dlstvalues" DataTextField="name" 
          AppendDataBoundItems="true">
   <asp:ListItem>-- Select --</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or this should work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically set the first one as selected.  You have to enter a default value into the drop down list and set it to the first item.

```
ddlName.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("<--Select-->", "0"));
```

Comment: Thank you also for your response.  This one works also for anyone coming through.  The problems was I also had a Dropdownlist1.Items.Clear() and had TOTALLY forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is happning because you may be binding your dorpdown on page load.
And you may not be checking for postback
Doing so it will bind the values again and you will get the new items in the dropdown list.
The previous `selected index` will not remain.

You should bind this in !isPostBack

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //bind data
}
```